# SQL: Having multiple conditional Averages between two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables

Sample from e.g. T1

```
----------------------
ID  || Operation Name |
----------------------|
101 || QA             |
----------------------
```

Sample from T 2

```
----------------------------------------
ID  || Employee  ID || Employee || Audit |
----------------------------------------
101 || 505788       || Marley   || 50    |
230 || 5487525      || Smith    || 100   |
-----------------------------------------
```

I should return each operation name with it's own Audit average  in conditions (if it's >= 90 as "Good" - if it's <90 and >= 40 as "Medium" - if it's < 40 as "Bad") and prevent any audit with average (0)

the table should be like this

```
---------------------------------------------------
Operation Name || Operation ID || Audit Evaluation |
----------------------------------------------------
Maintenance    ||   190        ||       Medium     |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Where does OperationID = 190 come from? How are the two tables linked to each other?

Comment: Operation ID is the ID in the first table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=61f71bb05eacd867592d6836b5d04db6)

```
SELECT
    t1.name AS operation_name,
    t1.id AS operation_id,
    CASE 
        WHEN AVG(t2.audit) >= 90 THEN 'Good'
        WHEN AVG(t2.audit) >= 40 THEN 'Medium'
        ELSE 'Bad'
    END AS audit_evaluation
FROM
    t1
JOIN
    t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name
HAVING AVG(t2.audit) > 0
```

1. Joining both tables on `id`
2. Grouping by their `id`s
3. `HAVING` filters out the `AVG = 0` groups
4. Calculating `AVG`
5. Using `CASE` clause to build the sections

Comment: Thanks a lot. BUT I want Medium to  <90 and > 40 in the same time, too. Any help.

Comment: a) What is with values that equal 90? b) It works as expected: If it is >90 then it would be taken the first one, if not, the next comparison takes part. So if it is <=90 and >40, this works.

Comment: Ok, added the >= comparators. Now it works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=61f71bb05eacd867592d6836b5d04db6

Comment: And for Medium, I don't have to say >= 40 ((And <90))? -- Just  >=40, Right?